# FileReference supports files larger than 4 gb... what's the point?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, large-files, filereference

Recently reading [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) manual on Adobe LiveDocs, I stumbled upon an interesting *note* in the description for the [size](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#size) property, that I've never noticed before:

> Note: In the initial version of ActionScript 3.0, the size property was defined as a uint object, which supported files with sizes up to about **4 GB**. It is now implemented as a Number object to support **larger files**.

...larger files? Larger then 4 GB?..

What's the point having support for such big files, if Flash still doesn't let to work with them without loading them into memory first? Or this has been changed? Or it's about AIR only?

Comment: Because, after all, 640k ought to... ;-)

Comment: Maybe a use can be uploading a BDAV(Blu-ray Disc Movie) file to a flash media server?

Comment: when i was testing loading large amounts of raw audio data via adobe stratus (aka cirrus) flash player died at about 800mb of ram used

Comment: @www0z0k it's weird, I remember the same thing, but when I tested today in Chrome and FF there was no hit on memory whatsoever... wtf? :O

Comment: did you try to run a http server locally and download some 4-5gb archive from there with flash. it might be writing data directly into the filesystem when downloading from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that this is about FlashPlayer's capabilities in any way. 
I think it simply was a general design flaw in the FileReference class. That class is supposed to model all possible file references. If the file system allows for files larger than 4gb and such can't be represented correctly by a FileReference instance this model does not do what it's supposed to - be able to represent all possible file references. 
The initial version just represented all file references to files below 4 gb in size. Someone noticed that flaw in the initial design and fixed it.